# Making new objects of different classes in a single for loop

Tags: java, instantiation

I'm slightly new to programming, and I am stuck. Say I have five different classes in a project: foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, and foo5 that all do different, but similar things. Now say I need to create a new object of each one, so something like:
    foo1 bar1 = new foo1();
    foo2 bar2 = new foo2();
    foo3 bar3 = new foo3();
and so on.
Sure that works, but I'm really trying to find a way to conserve a lot of space if I could instantiate all the objects I need in a single for-loop, or in the least put all the objects I want to create in a single Array to work out of. I can get it working if it was all the same Class, but not if it would be different. Is it even possible?

Comment: You should read about *what is polymorphism*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read something about polymorphism which you can use in Java. How does the  Interfaces and Abstract classes works. What is `extends` and `implements` keyword in Java and other ...

I found these tutorials which looks good:

[TutorialsPoint polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)

[Oracle polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the class name is in sequence, then you can use below:

```
For(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName("foo"+i);
        arr[i] = cls.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found " + e);
    }
}
```

But since all the objects are heterogeneous, the array will have to be of type `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [factory method pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is what you are looking for.

The task you are attempting to handle polymorphically is a bit different than the usual, since instantiation usually requires you to know the concrete type of the object you want to create. Factories will allow you to do this.

---

First, you need to ensure the types you want to instantiate derive from the same interface:

```
interface Foo { }
class Foo1 implements Foo { }
class Foo2 implements Foo { }
```

You can then define a factory type:

```
interface FooFactory {
    Foo createFoo();
}
```

Create implementations of `FooFactory` that return different types of `Foo`:

```
class Foo1Factory implements FooFactory {
    public Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo1();
    }
}

class Foo2Factory implements FooFactory {
    public Foo createFoo() {
        return new Foo2();
    }
}
```

Store these factories in an array:

```
FooFactory[] factories = {
    new Foo1Factory(),
    new Foo2Factory()
}
```

Then loop through the array, calling `createFoo()` on each factory:

```
for(FooFactory factory : factories) {
    Foo foo = factory.createFoo();
    //...
}
```